# Regex for number plus decimal point and number Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

```js
$(document).on("input", "#money", function() {
  if (/^\d*(\.\d+)/g.test($(this).val())) {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15)").removeClass("not");
  } else {
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid red").addClass("not");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="money" />
```

I want to have a regex for a money value. Meaning number one decimal point and number. The decimal point and number next should be optional.

Acceptable value:

```
100
100.00
```

Now it is not accepting if no decimal point also it is accepting multiple dots like:

```
100.12.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex [`^\d*(?:\.\d{2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/hCZUhL/3), it will match `100`, `100.00` and `.00` but not `100.000`, `100.00.0`, or `100.0`. If you want to allow `100.0` then use `^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`.

- `^` and `$` matches start and end of the input respectively. This avoid matching things like `foo100.00bar`
- `\d*` matches any number of digits
- `(?:...)?` matches what's inside the group optionally
- `\.\d{1,2}` matches a period and one or two digits

Comment: can you add a bit of explanation for each symbol for future readers?